# What is the tradeoff being made here? (push vs. Array)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am looking at an underscore.js function to retrieve the values from an object and am curious to understand the reason the _.values function was created the way it was.

The function as is in underscore.js:

```
  _.values = function(obj) {
    var keys = _.keys(obj);
    var length = keys.length;
    var values = Array(length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      values[i] = obj[keys[i]];
    }
    return values;
  };
```

I believe this would also work however:

```
  _.values = function(obj) {
    var keys = _.keys(obj);
    var length = keys.length;
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      values.push(obj[keys[i]]);
    }
    return values;
  };
```

What is the tradeoff between using function #1 vs. #2. Is it simply for performance or is there other things?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach allows the JS runtime to immediately allocate the correct amount of memory.

Calling `push()` on an empty array will force the array to resize as it gets full, wasting time and memory.

Comment: Intuition for arrays from C-like languages often breaks down in JS. Can you explain in more detail why this works intuitively here?

Comment: @djechlin: Because modern JS runtimes are very smart, and will try to be more C-like.  (the precise answer is that arrays are implemented like Java ArrayList as opposed to a hash table, where appropriate)